# WHERE IN query?

Tags: mysql, where-in

With the next database:
[image: G]

I need to select all soldiers who have been **ONLY** in battles in their own planet and I don't have any idea of how can I make it.

This is what I've tried.

```
SELECT id_soldier, name 
FROM soldier, battle_log, battle 
WHERE IN(...soldier.planet_id = battle.id_planet_battle...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have access to the db I can't test it but can you give this a try?

```
SELECT id_soldier, name 
FROM soldier s 
LEFT JOIN battle_log l ON s.id_soldier = l.soldier_id 
LEFT JOIN battle b ON l.battle_id = b.id_battle 
WHERE s.planet_id = b.id_planet_battle
```

If it returns an error just let me know and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: @javipedrera Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `not exists` operator to exclude soldiers who participated in battles on other planets:

```
SELECT *
FROM   soldier s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   battle b
                   JOIN   battle_log bl ON b.id_battle = bl.battle_id
                   WHERE  bl.soldier_id = s.id_soldier AND
                          b.id_planet_battle != s.planet_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. You helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you can use simple query and join this step.

If I understand correctly soldier join planet **(soldier have own planet)**
Then join Battle by planet **(because planet that soldier have it's have battle)**

Comment: You have a shorter path if you join soldier with battle_log and finally battle ;)

Comment: Ah... In fact my flow have only 3 main entity (soldier,planet and battle) equal your flow :)

Comment: But if you don't add battle_log how do you know if the soldier fought a battle on a certain planet?